# mod_security forcing to redirect to Apache test page

Tags: mod-security

i have installed drupal and installed couple of modules to provide the admin export to excel feature. when i click on the export button the page is getting redirected to Apache test page. I have done some R&D and commented #Include modsecurity.d/base_rules/*.conf in mod_security works fine. But i would not prefer to comment the base_rules as there may security threats.

I have not seen any errors in apache error logs. Any suggestion to fix.

Reference link on Drupal Stack.
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198602/view-data-export-page-regdirecting-to-the-apache-error-page

Comment: Enable logging for mod_security & see which request it's blocking & which modsec rule caused it. https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecDebugLog

Comment: I have added Sec DebugLog                                                                   [code] <IfModule mod_security2.c>
Include modsecurity.d/*.conf
Include modsecurity.d/base_rules/*.conf
Include modsecurity.d/modsecurity_localrules.conf
SecDataDir /export/data/****/apache_logs
SecDebugLog /export/data/*******/apache_logs/modsec/modsec-debug.log</IfModule> [code]                                                                                 I have noticed the log file is created but there are no log items in the file. Any help?

Comment: Set value -> SecDebugLogLevel 9 and restart, access page and check the logs again

Comment: Thank you friend. Now the logs are logged in the file. But unfortunately i see logs are filled with 65MB for 2 page refreshes. How do i find the exact issue?

Comment: I have updated SecDebugLogLevel 9 with 1, 2 and 3 and see there are no logs updated.

Comment: @serverliving.com Appreciate your suggestions.